# Is there a design pattern for a class storing information needed by another class, for example for its construction?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have classes that depends on various parameters, in particular in their constructor.

```
class Foo {
  Foo(int foo, double bar);
  // no default constructor
};
```

When `Foo` is used from another class, I sometimes need to store intermediate values needed by `Foo`. This happens when `Foo` depends on one or several values that are not readily available when the object using `Foo` is created.

I can store those values in the client class, but when this class uses several objects like `Foo` I end up having many parameters that relates to `Foo`-like objects. Therefore I usually end-up creating a class that holds these parameters and can create an object when all necessary parameters are eventually collected.

My question is, is there already a named pattern for this, and what is this name? I don't think Factory is the correct name because the intent of a Factory is different and closely related to inheritance. Or, is this approach wrong, and what would be a superior solution?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean and want to achieve? What is "depends on several values". Do you mean having data members?

Answer (score 1):

The [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) lets you defer the construction of an object over e.g. several method calls. It can also increase the flexibility of how you create objects.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything needs to be a full-blown class and not every problem needs a pattern. You could simply use a

```
struct FooParams {
    int foo;
    double bar;
};
```

such that the user can first collect the parameters and then create the instance:

```
FooParams p;
p.foo = getTheFoo();
p.bar = getTheBar();
Foo f(p);
```

However, if you have many different constructors this does not scale well and you might want to take a look at the builder pattern as suggested by a different answer.